# chart.js dynamically add y axes from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a generic script to create charts for multiple graphs.
I want to populate multiple y axes, based on the json response I would get from the web API.

If my json is as below:

```
  '{ "GraphName": "test", "GraphType": 0, "GraphOptionsCollection": [{ "yLabel": "label1", "yAxisPosition": 0, "backgroundColor": "blue", , "name": "prop1" }, { "yLabel": "label2", "yAxisPosition": 1, "backgroundColor": "yellow",  "name": "prop2" }] }';
```

would it be possible to dynamically add a new  y axis to chart.options.yAxes collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can update chart options and then call [update()](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#updateconfig) method on your chart instance.

For example:

1. initially create a secondary Y axe with `display: false;`
2. update secondary Y axe options when needed and then update chart

See my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/hw8ozgh4/

Comment: Yes, this works when we upfront know on the number of Y axes we will have. however, in cases where are more than 2 vertical axes this approach would not help.

Comment: However, if you have a max # of y axes, you could adopt this approach. On the other hand, as shown in my fiddle, addition of new axes seems not to be supported.

Comment: There is an open issue for adding/updating scales; see https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4541. chart.updates() is intended for minor updates, so I think addding new axes is not the case.